# Paypal HTML form - instant return to URL

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I am making a paypal form so people can donate any amount they want. It is working perfectly, but i have some problems with the return-url. Right now, it only return when people manually click "return to ****" after payment, but i need it to go back to the url automatically right after the payment is completed. How do i do that?

Here is the code for my form: http://pastebin.com/pHY3gfZn

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few different options with PayPal Standard to setup Auto Return. 
You can use the following code:

`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://yourReturnWebsiteHere.com">`

The other way is by setting up **Auto Return** and **Payment Data Transfer**
Below comes from the PayPal official Documentation on **Auto Return.**

**Auto Return** allows merchants to return their buyers to their website upon payment completion. It replaces the PayPal-hosted **"Payment Done"** page with a page hosted on the merchant's website.

To set up **Auto Return**, merchants turn it on and specify the **Return URL** that will be used to redirect buyers back to their website. The Return URL is applied to all their Auto Return payments unless otherwise specified within the button or link for that website payment.

For more information, please see the Website Payments Standard Integration Guide, which is available at: [PayPal Payments Standard Integration Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf)

Once you have set up **Auto Return**, you can use **Payment Data Transfer** to display the payment details to your buyer.

Your buyers can return to your website automatically after they make a payment.

Here's how to set the auto return preference:

1. Go to www.paypal.com and log in to your account.
2. Click **Profile near** the top of the page.
3. Click **My Selling tools.**
4. Click Update beside 'Website preferences.'
5. Select '**On**' next to '**Auto Return**.'
6. Specify the page buyers will be redirected to next to '**Return URL**,'
   then click **Save.**

**Note:**

- If you use Subscriptions Password Management or plan to use it, Auto Return must be turned off to display the PayPal-generated username and password to buyers.
- If you turn on both Auto Return and PayPal Account Optional, new buyers aren't automatically returned to your website, but are given the option to return.
- If you turn on Auto Return, you can use Payment Data Transfer to display the payment details to buyers.

For more information on Payment Data Transfer, click the below link:
[Payment Data Transfer Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/)

Comment: I am currently using <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://yourReturnWebsiteHere.com">, but i want it to return instantly after purchase, instead of having to press "go back to ****" manually

Comment: Auto return works for PayPal users on PayPal Payments Standard, however, any one that pays as a guest on your site will not be returned to your website automatically. They will receive the link to redirect to your website. The only way you can ensure all users are automatically taken back to your website is to turn off "Account optional" in your PayPal account. This would ensure all of your buyers have a PayPal account or create a PayPal in order to receive payments. This would also ensure that all users are redirected to your website with auto return.

Comment: One of my friends donated. He donated from a paypal account, but he had to manually click "go back". How do i get rid of that?

Comment: Make certain that Auto Return is turned on in both your PayPal Account and in the button to ensure that it will auto return to your website. It should say redirecting in 5 seconds when a PayPal account is used.